# Enable unresolved attribute inspection in PyCharm

Tags: pycharm

There is a lot of question about disabling an inspection. But I can't find how to enable it back. Actually I have disable it one for a single class and it seams it is not checking anything more. I would like to get back the normal inspection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to `File -> Settings -> Editor -> Inspections`. There's a list of all inspections for different languages. Go to *Python* list and find `Unresolved references`. Check it to enable particular inspection.

*Note*: Inspections are defined for current project only. To enable (or disable) inspection for new projects, you should go to settings from PyCharm start screen.